# Error “Expression type ambiguous without more context”

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift3

Переношу проект с swift 1 на swift 3, выдает ошибку. Подскажите как убрать. Спасибо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Данные методы являются методами супер класса, это значит то, что вы должны их переопределить в Вашем классе - `override`.

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
 }
```